# Linux license in a European company

Tags: linux-distribution

I would like to install Ubuntu or Debian Desktop on a PC from our company which is in the European Community. I was told that the company should pay for this license, because in EU they must.

Do you know anything about this? I think the company does not have to pay,  only if they want support assistance or if Ubuntu Enterprise is installed.

Comment: Who told you this, and what resources did they provide as a backup for their claims?

Comment: A workmate who worked in a multinational compmany in USA. She told she got a workmate who wanted to install Linux in a PC and he didnt get allowed because the company had to pay for that license

Comment: It sounds like there's a telephone game going on in which the actual situation got mangled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, let me give you my Paypal account. I am the sole receiver for Linux license payments for Europe.... Just kidding.

More seriously, while you can buy support subscriptions for Linux from Ubuntu or RedHat, you can typically download and use freely these distros (at least Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS and OpenSuse) as well as Debian which is the hallmark of freedom.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I though but no clue why i got told this ._.  it made me doubt thats why I asked

Comment: @Neuls I am still waiting for my check :D $$. Happy holidays.

Comment: -sending check- happy xmas